# I'm trying to plot a space in real life that has four sides but none are equal or parralel.

Tags: geometry

I'm using graph paper, each box equaling 1 foot square. I pulled right angles, (BCE and ADF) cutting a right triangle off at each end and measuring, but the math is not adding up $A^2+B^2=C^2$.  All I can figure is I'm making drastic errors finding those right angles, but I've done it 3 times.  AB=42'4", BC=28'3", CD=47'6", DA=36'8". I'm no surveyor, obviously, and many years away from the higher math I learned in high school ... just wondering if I've missed something you can see right off.
Many thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

To draw a quadrilateral you need 5, not 4 dimensions. *An extra diagonal* apart from the four sides.Each of the the two triangles has all 3 sides with a shared diagonal known, so can be constructed.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me.  I have found that my math was sound but my writing was NOT.  Once I corrected that, everything added up as it should have.  I mistook a 2 for a 1.  The perils of writing on one's knee with a ball point pen. It's always the basics that matter in the end.